# Install flash component manually

Tags: drupal, module

i have a flash module folder that has a swf, some xml and swc, and some other folders for resources in it.

For this module to work on a custom site i have to include two scripts in the  area and also a div with a specific class value.

I haven't find a way how to do it, i have only worked with Joomla.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You must edit template of the theme you are using. In order to find which template to edit i suggest to install this module : http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer (help and description there : http://drupal.org/node/209561)

Then it's very simple, you just have to edit template that are written in PHP.

Comment: i found a file under sites/all/themes which is called template.php . If i change this file, then where do i save the rest folders that come with the component?

Comment: No there are .tpl.php file in you themes directory.